# Is it possible to turn the magnifying frame off in live view on a EOS 1200D?

Tags: low-light

I'm trying to take photos of stars with a tracker unit.

When I switch to live view the magnifying frame is so bright I can't see the stars I'm trying to photograph.

Is there any way to turn it off?